# JavaFX freezes when I start the thread - I'm using Runlater command

Tags: java, multithreading, gluon

I have a simple thread like this.

public class CameraThread extends Thread {

```
    private AtomicBoolean runCamera;

    public CameraThread(AtomicBoolean runCamera) {
        this.runCamera = runCamera;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (Main.RUNTHREAD) {
            while (runCamera.get()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    threadSleep();
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void threadSleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I set `runCamera` to `runCamera.set(true)` utside from the thread, the whole GUI freezes and I cannot do anything.

This is a minimal example and I can't get it to work properly.
I have used `RunLater` command before, but this time, I'm sitting at a `Dell precision M6400` machine from 2007. Could it happen that this machine cannot handle threads with Java?

Or how can I solve this issue?

To reproduce this issue, just type the following:

```
wget https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Darknet-Data-Creator/archive/main.zip
unzip Darknet-Data-Creator-main.zip
cd Darknet-Data-Creator-main
mvn javafx:run
```

Then click on `Scan` button, select a web camera (USB, laptop camera) and then press `Save to folder` button. Just select some arbitary folder. Then press `Open camera` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `Thread.Sleep()` inside `Platform.runLater(...)`, which means that you are sleeping the GUI, not your camera thread.

Try this instead, note how runLater is outside of the `Platform.runLater` code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (Main.RUNTHREAD) {
        while (runCamera.get()) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            });
            //Now thread sleep is outside of runLater:
            threadSleep();
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that should go inside the runlater is things that directly change the GUI. Any calculation, sleeping, processing, file reading etc should be kept separate.